# When an entry is deleted from the datastore, is its corresponding search document also deleted?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-search-api

I am using Google App Engine's [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) to index entities from the Datastore.   After I create or modify an object, I have to add it to the Search index.  I do this by creating a `add_to_search_index` method for each model whose entities are indexed, for example:

```
class Location(ndb.Model):
  ...
  def add_to_search_index(self):
    fields = [
       search.TextField(name="name", value=self.name),
       search.GeoField(name="location", value= search.GeoPoint(self.location.lat, self.location.lon)),
             ]
    document = search.Document(doc_id=str(self.key.id()), fields=fields)
    index = search.Index(name='Location_index')
    index.put(document)
```

Does the search API automatically maintain any correspondence between indexed documents and datastore entities?

I suspect they are not, meaning that the Search API will maintain deleted, obsolete entities in its index.  If that's the case, then I suppose the best approach would be to use the [NDB hook methods](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass) to create a `remove_from_search_index` method that is called before `put` (for edits/updates) and `delete`.  Please advise if there is a better solution for maintaining correspondence between the datastore and search indices.

Comment: No. And, yes, use the NDB hook methods to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Since the datastore (NDB) and the search API are separate back ends they are to be maintained separately. I see you're using the `key.id()` as the document id. You can use this document id to get a document or to delete it. Maintaining the creation of the search document can be done in the model's `_post_put_hook` and `_post_delete_hook`. You may also use the repository pattern to do this. How you do this is up to you.

```
index = search.Index(name='Location_index')
index.delete([doc_id])
```